Select points within distance to other points
I am working on a procedural city generator. I would like to select all islands/faces that are within a proximity to any other faces.
In other words, I would like to select all faces within distance x to each other.
I tried many ways I found online but I could get none to work. I know the math for that is in Blender since the Merge by Distance node does that trivially; I just wish to, instead of merge, select these islands.
Thank you so much for any hints!



What would you like to select it for? Because they are already been selected. See the pink-colored output from the math node is the selection. And shouldn't you switch the evaluate node to 'faces'?

It unfortunately does not work. It either outputs all buildings or none. I want to select it to evaluate if the building is a free standing building (minimum 3m distance to other buildings) or not

You could say i try to select all buildings that are less or equal than 3m distant from each other

Do you want to select "faces" or "islands/buildings"?

Islands, the building footprints are polygons of several connected faces

Given a selected island index, these nodes separate all that are near.
(You can transform this node into a "Tool" and use "set selection" at the end instead of "separate geometry" too)
The subdivision level is intended to add precision. Instead of doing complicated math to find "point to face" distances, subdividing and doing "point to point" distance is easier, but not precise.

Point distances
This group calculates the smallest distance between all points and the points of the selected island:

Filter islands
This group gets the min distance for each island and filters it in or out.

File


Thank you so much!!!! Your answer is really good, thanks a lot it helps. Though, is it possible to calculate this for every island? Would it need a nested repeat zone or is that not possible/something else more viable?

@ak97,  the only way I can think of it at this moment is having a nested repeat. I tried searching aroud for "grouped attribute statistic" (where the results would be "fields" instead of single values), but the solutions I found were so bizarrely big/complicated that I gave up. Maybe one day I get some insight.

I also haven't figured a way to work with "2d data" in geometry nodes. All its conception was intended for "1d data" only . So, there are two repeats there, one because of the 2d data aspect (one array of points vs another array of points), another because of the attribute statistic.
